# Elastic search query part ignored

Tags: elasticsearch

I currently working on a new search features using elastic search, and I'm struggling with getting my data.
When I send my request to the elastic it seems like the engine ignore part of my query.

my query:

```
GET products_index_Active/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "categories",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "categories.categoryName": {
                        "value": "Electronics"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "categories.displayStatus": [
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 0,
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "searchable": {
                    "query": "headphones",
                    "boost": 2,
                    "_name": "ProductSearchableJoined_MatchPhrase"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "dealName": {
                    "query": "headphones",
                    "slop": 20,
                    "boost": 3,
                    "_name": "ProductNameJoined_MatchPhrase_Slop20"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "productName": {
                    "query": "headphones",
                    "boost": 4,
                    "_name": "ProductNameJoined_MatchPhrase"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
            
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So my must condition work perfectly except its not... its seems like the query gets all the products that under "Electronics" category but ignoring my should query where all my logic for search is. I found out that must and should cannot be on the same level and I need to move my should query into the must query as another term. I tried to place it **everywhere** in the must query with zero success.

any suggestion?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your description properly- Should at least one of the should clauses match?

Comment: `"minimum_should_match": 0` is not correct. Should be at least 1

Comment: @Val, according to the doc, `0` is valid if you have a `must` clause. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match

Or I am missing something ?

Comment: @IgalAchourov,  could you give us some test documents please ? as well as the mapping ?

Comment: @Paulo, having 0 here means that it's ok that none of the should clause match, which means none of those conditions are useful... If you want at least one to match (like in an OR condition) you need to have at least 1

Comment: @RussCam yes I need one of the should clauses to match. @Val changed "minimum_should_match" to 1 with no difference. @Paulo unfortunately I can`t give the mapping and test docs because of organization privacy, but if I remove the must clause its work properly and same about the should.